# Flippign Lettesr Aroudn

Tags: code-golf, string

In chat, we are often fast-typers and don't really look at the [order](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41967809#41967809) of [letters](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41967812#41967812) before posting a message. Since we are lazy, we need a program that automatically swaps the last two letters in our words, but since we don't want to respond too late, the code must be short.

Your task, if you wish to accept it, is to write a program that flips the last two letters of each word in a given string (so the word `Thansk` turns into `Thanks`). A *word* is a sequence of two or more letters in the English alphabet delimited by **a single** space.

- The string / list of *characters* you receive as input is guaranteed to only contain alphabetic characters and spaces (ASCII [97 - 122], [65 - 90] and 32).
- You can take input and provide output through any [standard method](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods), in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2073/59487), while taking note that [these loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden by default.
- The output may have one trailing space and / or one trailing newline.
- The input will always contain words only (and the corresponding whitespace) and will consist of at least one word.

This is code-golf, so the shortest submission (scored in bytes), in each language wins!

#### Test cases

Note that the strings are surrounded with quotes for readability.

```
Input -> Output

"Thansk"                                 -> "Thanks"
"Youer welcoem"                          -> "Youre welcome"
"This is an apple"                       -> "Thsi si na appel"
"Flippign Lettesr Aroudn"                -> "Flipping Letters Around"
"tHe oDd chALlEneg wiht swappde lettesR" -> "teH odD chALlEnge with swapped letteRs"
```

Or, for test suite convenience, here are the inputs and their corresponding outputs separately:

```
Thansk
Youer welcoem
This is an apple
Flippign Lettesr Aroudn
tHe oDd chALlEneg wiht swappde lettesR
```

```
Thanks
Youre welcome
Thsi si na appel
Flipping Letters Around
teH odD chALlEnge with swapped letteRs
```

Thanks to [DJMcMayhem](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31716/djmcmayhem) for the title. This was originally a [CMC](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/41967829#41967829).

Comment: May we output an array of words?

Comment: @Shaggy No, the output must be a string (or a list of characters by default)

Comment: May we request a trailing space on each input?

Comment: @FlipTack It [was allowed](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/revisions/151890/2) in the initial version, but I have removed that rule before any of the answers that would use that had been posted. (partly because some users in chat told me I'm making this too easy otherwise, and I agree with them). No, it's not allowed.

Comment: Whta shoudl eb doen wiht oen lettre worsd liek "a"?

Comment: @Fabian *A word is a sequence **of two or more** letters*

Answer (score 16):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 4 <s>5</s> bytes

```
òeXp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcsxDsIwEETR3qeYq0QCRJEKpYDSikexxbJe2Q6@F1fgYCZC@uX77zG@H95tjCV6rU/3yDsLOmXNfLklpoojr/BmQneRZJY2xczWWAumkvegrl2JfApY4zTLWbmhp9hQ@7EFQv769gM)

`||` denotes the cursor

The buffer starts with `|w|ord and more words` and the cursor being on the first character.

Recursively `ò`

go to the `e`nd of a word

`wor|d| and more words`

remove `X` the character to the left of the cursor

`wo|d| and more words`

`p`aste it over the next character

`wod|r| and more words`

Implicit ending `ò`, repeat the same process for other words until the end of the buffer is reached

Comment: The right language for the task :)

Comment: Do you mean "Repeatedly" instead of "Recursively"?

Comment: @NieDzejkob The V wiki uses the word "recursively" to describe the `ò` command https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V/wiki/Normal-Mode-Commands

Answer (score 10):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
Ḳœ?@€2K
```

A monadic link taking and returning lists of characters

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk1HJ9s7PGpaY@T9//9/JbeczIKCzPQ8BZ/UkpLU4iIFx6L80pQ8JQA)**

#### How?

```
Ḳœ?@€2K - Link: list of characters
Ḳ       - split at spaces
     2  - literal two
    €   - for €ach:
   @    -   with sw@pped arguments:
 œ?     -     nth permutation (the 2nd permutation has the rightmost elements swapped)
      K - join with spaces
```

Comment: That's a nice abuse of permutations. [Alternative](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk1GRyfbqzxqWuP9//9/JbeczIKCzPQ8BZ/UkpLU4iIFx6L80pQ8JQA)

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder `Ḳ2œ?Ð€K` also works and uses a single quick.

Answer (score 9):

## [Brain-Flak](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/Brain-Flak), 122 bytes

```
{(({})[((((()()){}){}){}){}])((){[()](<{}>)}{}){{}<>(({}({}))[({}[{}])])(<>)}{}({}<>)<>}<>(({}({}))[({}[{}])]){({}<>)<>}<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dYs9CoAwDIWv4pgMvUHpKdxKhyr@FKWD7RZy9pgIgovhLXnv@6Yrl@rWMx8iBECMEewQEPV5k1ArioAJPHFAtpbYB1PMUo04GqiofwCwHX34oeizi4x7aYOmL62Xuombbw)

The worst language for the job :)

<s>Readable</s> Slightly more readable version:

```
{
    (({})[((((()()){}){}){}){}])((){[()](<{}>)}{})

    {
        {}
        <>

        (({}({}))[({}[{}])])

        (<>)
    }
    {}

    ({}<>)<>

}<>

(({}({}))[({}[{}])])

{

    ({}<>)
    <>
}<>
```

Comment: I can't believe this is longer than the Brainfuck version...

Comment: @pureferret Brain-flak tends to be longer than brainfuck. Mostly cause it requires two bytes per primitive command, where brain-flak requires two.

Answer (score 7):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 50 bytes

```python
print(*(w[:-2]+w[:-3:-1]for w in input().split()))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/v6AoM69EQ0ujPNpK1yhWG0QZW@kaxqblFymUK2TmAVFBaYmGpl5xQU4mkNbU/P@/JCOzWAGIkvNTUtPzc9IA)

This answer abuses Python 3's behavior of print: Multiple arguments are printed with a single space between them. Of course, we can't just give it multiple arguments because we don't know how many words will be in the input. So we use  the [splat operator](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2322355/3524982). Basically

```python
print(*[a,b,c])
```

is exactly the same thing as

```python
print(a,b,c)
```

Abusing that makes a full program turn out shorter than a function/lambda where we'd have to use `' '.join` or something similar.

Comment: Looks like Python 2 saves 2 bytes by writing `for w in input().split():print w[:-2]+w[:-3:-1],`. In Python 3, extracting the last two characters would work well with `print(*(''.join(a)+c+b for*a,b,c in input().split()))` except that `a` needs to be remade into a string.

Answer (score 7):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 40 bytes

```hs
(f=<<).words
f[a,b]=b:a:" "
f(x:r)=x:f r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcGxDoIwEADQna@4NA6QqB/Q0MHFyY1RHA7o1cZaLtcS@HrP995YPj4lDW7Ullzfd9d9laU09MTz9HKTRWvANNQeVjp3WALRL8YMDnirQxU4QQBzT5E5hgwPX6svAjdZtyUb/c2UMBS9zMx/) Usage example: `(f=<<).words $ "abc xyz"` yields `"acb xzy "`.

Comment: So you're telling me the shortest approach is both the approaches combined? >_<

Answer (score 7):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 13 bytes

```
(.)(.)\b
$2$1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcuxCsIwEIDh/Z7ihg66CPoGBRWHTtKl4BKbozk8LyG5ksePQfjG/89krK61w@nYvd4wXIZza3NwWj6wxJ0yVpI10hfmwAU7p@hSEoK7cEq8KU5kRiXjmOPuFexBGK8e1zBOclPasHIwLLVvnlD@9fMH) Link includes test cases.

Answer (score 5):

## C,  <s>62</s>   <s>58</s>  54 bytes

*Thanks to @Dennis for saving  <s>four</s>  eight bytes!*

```
f(char*s){s[1]>32||(*s^=s[-1]^=*s^=s[-1]);*++s&&f(s);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XZBBa8MwDIXv/hWCQRun7Vg7tkuWQmEbO/Q0ehlZCsFRYjPXCZFDDm1@e2a3I4EJHcR7Tx9CYlUKMQxFIGTWhMTPlKzT7ePmcglCOsaUrNbpMR5HHoWLBc1mRUA86oc7ZYRuc4QXsrmq7uWWMWUsnDJlAs7ODFx5MpBtks3TcxpdpU4qjRAUJVoKnLUE5y3BQwzn18ht15cHaog9QqPxcR5NZgFeSbQ7DuIY5t9mzkd3gviacvAwEfpxKv6x6/Z23Z/Us344yMzQD/uqWmygQy0qPLGDVASuMwNZXWtk71rVtSoN7NFapAZ2TdXmhtkPhOo1dx/Z7fWbwRI6JS1Q59bcE/U1/fkL)

Comment: ah, the xor-based swap

Comment: How is `s[-1]` safe? I get how it works in the recursive runs (at the end after `*++s`), but on the first pass shouldn't it be undefined behavior?

Answer (score 5):

## [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) (R2016b), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

Saved <s>49</s> 50 (!) bytes thanks to @Giuseppe.

```
function s(a),regexprep(a,'(\w)(\w)( |$)','$2$1 ')
```

And my previous answer:

## [Matlab](https://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab.html) (R2016b), 100 bytes

(Just for the fun of it :P)

```
function s(a),a=regexp(a,' ','split');for i=1:length(a),fprintf('%s ',a{i}([1:end-2 end end-1])),end
```

Explanation:

```
function s(a) % Defining as a function...
a=regexp(a,' ','split'); % Splits the input string at the spaces
for i=1:length(a) % Loops through each word
    fprintf('%s ',a{i}([1:end-2 end end-1])) % And prints everything with the last two characters swapped.
end
```

Comment: one character words can't happen, as a word is defined to be at least two characters.

Comment: would `regexprep` work here? Something like `regexprep(a,'(\w*)(\w)(\w)','\1\3\2')`?

Comment: D= This. Was. Epic! I think you should post this answer, since it's totally different from mine. The only thing is that Matlab references the matches with `$1`, and not `\1`, so it would be `regexprep(a,'(\w*)(\w)(\w)','$1$3$2')`.

Comment: you should post it as a separate answer / in this answer; it's always good to see if a regex would help or not on a string challenge!

Besides, I clearly don't understand MATLAB's regex engine, so it wouldn't quite be fair for me to take credit for it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Giuseppe! And it doesn't even break with the 1 letter words!

Comment: `function s(a),regexprep(a,'(\w)(\w)( |$)','$2$1 ')` is still another byte shorter!

Answer (score 4):

## [Prolog (SWI)](http://www.swi-prolog.org), 60 bytes

```
[A,B]+[B,A].
[A,B,32|U]+[B,A,32|Y]:-U+Y,!.
[A|U]+[A|Y]:-U+Y.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKz8lP1y0uz/z/P9pRxylWO9pJxzFWjwvE0TE2qgmFiICYkbFWuqHakTqKIFmwhCNMTO///8SS/Nz45PyU1GIN9ZLU4hKF4pKizLx0dR1noJgmmNSO0EFS5ZIKonUiNPUA)

### Explanation

First we define the base case:

```
p([A,B],[B,A]).
```

This means that the last two letters will always be swapped.

Then we define what happens if we are right next to a space:

```
p([A,B,32|U],[B,A,32|Y]):-p(U,Y),!.
```

Two strings match if right before a space the letters before the space are swapped and the remainder if the strings match.  We then use `!` to cut.

Our last case is if we are not next to a space the first two letters need to match.

```
p([A|U],[A|Y]):-p(U,Y).
```

Answer (score 4):

## [R](http://www.r-project.org), <s>111</s> <s>51</s> 41 bytes

Courtesy of @Giuseppe, a regex approach which blows my old method out of the water.

```
cat(gsub("(.)(.)\\b",'\\2\\1',scan(,"")))
```

Comment: regex are much more efficient here: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJQ0kjJqZcSxNEQgglHfWYGMOYGOOYGCN1neLkxDwNHSUlTU3N/0puOZkFBZnpeQo@qSUlqcVFCo5F@aUpeUr/AQ "R – Try It Online")

Comment: (not that I don't appreciate the guts it takes to do a pure string manipulation approach in R)

Comment: [84 byte golf of your approach](https://tio.run/##FcuxCgIxDIDhVwmdUsyB5@7g4uQbiMNR41kouZhE6NvXc/iXD34b47UZdqgCHubaaqCXRZBSyv9yWQL73fmDPR8KGiseqbGs8d5lOmWaaZrzgxIkctbzPo1rq6p1FbhxBLvBxbbvU8YP "R – Try It Online")

Comment: @Giuseppe Wow, nice work! I've edited them into my answer, although if you'd prefer to make your own answer please go ahead!

Comment: nah, don't worry about it. I golfed down [another 10 bytes:](https://tio.run/##K/r/PzmxRCO9uDRJQ0lDTxOIYmKSlHTUY2KMYmIM1XWKkxPzNHSUlDQ1Nf8rueVkFhRkpucp@KSWlKQWFyk4FuWXpuQp/QcA) porting another regex approach, and a [70 byte](https://tio.run/##K/r/Py2/SKNCITNPobikqLggJ7NEozg5MU9DR0lJE4Q1kxNLNDJSE1M0KnR0jTR1ilLLNCo0ow2tjGJ1lBSUdIpTC2yByv675WQWFGSm5yn4pJaUpBYXKTgW5Zem5P0HAA) of your old approach

Answer (score 4):

## [Wolfram Language](http://reference.wolfram.com), 117 bytes

```
StringReplace[RegularExpression["\\b[[:alpha:]]{2,}\\b"]:>StringDrop[StringInsert["$0",StringTake["$0",{-1}],-3],-1]]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYvBasMwEETv/YpF9OjQpr0ZWhpISgs5FNeXouiwsTeWiCwJaY0Lxt/uKjXswM4bXo@sqUc2DS6Xl@Wbo3FdRcFiQ7KibrAYD78hUkrGOylOp7OUJdqgsVRqeirmTIQqX1dzH32Q6/vpEkWW4v5RFCup8UprnzbbWRWb55ytUstXXhkkXODhDSZRa3TpKgoQP36gCCPZxlN/A7U2CfKhAwzBUmZ3AOLdmhBM5@BIzJQi7KIfWncz@IPA71to9O5oD446GI1mSGP2WwL7L1RiBrX8AQ)

Applied to the test strings.

```
StringReplace[
  RegularExpression["\\b[[:alpha:]]{2,}\\b"] :> 
   StringDrop[StringInsert["$0", StringTake["$0", {-1}], -3], -1]] /@
 {"Thansk", "Youer welcoem", "This is an apple", 
  "Flippign Lettesr Aroudn", "tHe oDd chALlEneg wiht swappde lettesR"} // Column
```

> ```
> Thanks
> Youre welcome
> Thsi si na appel
> Flipping Letters Around
> teH odD chALlEnge with swapped letteRs
> ```

Comment: Welcome to PPCG!

Answer (score 4):

## [APL (Dyalog Classic)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 28 bytes

```
1↓∊((¯2↓⊢),2↑⌽)¨' '(,⊂⍨⊣=,)⍞
```

`⎕ML` and `⎕IO` are both `1`,

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT9dNzkksLs5M/v//Ud/UR20TDB@1TX7U0aWhcWi9EYjZtUhTB8iY@Khnr@ahFeoK6ho6j7qaHvWueNS12FZH81HvvP//g/NzU0syMvPSFYoS81LycxXS81OLFTJSi1IB)

## Explanation

- **`... (,⊂⍨⊣=,) ...`** Split (while keeping borders, and appending a border to the beginning) ...
- **`... ⍞`** ... the input ...
- **`... ' ' ...`** ... at spaces.
- **`... ( ... )¨ ...`** Then, to each element of that:

  - **`... , ...`** Concatenate ...
  - **`... (¯2↓⊢) ...`** ... every item except the last two ...
  - **`... 2↑⌽ ...`**  ... with the reverse of the last two elements.
- **`1↓∊ ...`** Finally, return all but the first element of the flattened result.

Comment: *return all but the **first***

Answer (score 3):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 45 bytes

*-2 bytes thanks to H.PWiz.*

```hs
(r.g.r=<<).words
g(x:y:z)=' ':y:x:z
r=reverse
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcY7DoQgEADQ3lNMjIlayAGIcwpbG4IDbhYXMvg/vLO@6s0mfykEcThKw8orxr5v1RF5yoVvTn3pu8Ua6jenvgtGpp04kyzm8wOEtK3DylCBg/KKGxMcFGxcqJTHumB8ls6m9Ac)

Answer (score 3):

## [Funky](https://github.com/TehFlaminTaco/Funky), 34 bytes

```
s=>s::gsub("(.)(.)( |$)","$2$1$3")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyvNy678n2b7v9jWrtjKKr24NElDSUNPE4QUalQ0lXSUVIxUDFWMlTT/FxRl5pVopGlk5usVpSamaGhqav4v8UhVyHdJUUjOcPTJcc1LTVcoz8woUSguTywoSElVyEktKUktDgIA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <s>20 19</s> 11 bytes

Credit to @Bolce Bussiere

```
1&A.&.>&.;:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYzBCgIhGITvPcWc1pvQtSgQKjrsKfbSUfTf1TIVdfHxbQlCmMvMNzOv1uYTx34QfODngR8PjZQJmMEmI31@s93fP8NKCZWcCvTp8WRsxibpIWN01MnN2Rjt4jFSKZQTRAqr9r1Q7oRw0VBGjO7qaUG1piDX7UgT3G/2YO0L)

```
       &.;:      on words
    &.>          on each
  A.             apply the permutation
1&               number 1, swap the last two elements
```

Comment: 13 Bytes with `(1&A.&.>)&.;:`

Comment: @BolceBussiere perfect

Comment: Could you add an explanation? Wondering if I can port it to K to reduce the embarrassing byte count of my solution!

Answer (score 3):

### [Alice](https://github.com/m-ender/alice), 24 bytes

```
/0RR'.%$1\' o
\ix*o ne@/
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8zJTE79/1/fIChIXU9VxTBGXSGfKyazQitfIS/VQf///5CMzGIFIErMU0gsKMhJBQA)

#### Explanation

```
/...\' o
\.../
```

This forms a loop where the loop body is a linear Ordinal snippet and we execute `' o` in Cardinal mode between every two loop iterations. The latter just prints a space.

Unfolding the zigzag structure of the Ordinal code, the linear loop body actually looks like this:

```
iR*' %e10xRo.n$@
```

Breaking this down:

```
i     Read all input. On subsequent iterations, this will push an empty string.
R     Reverse.
*     Join. On the first iteration, this joins the input to an implicit empty string,
      which does nothing. On subsequent iterations, it will join the empty string to
      the word on top of the string, thereby getting rid of the empty string.
' %   Split around spaces. On the first iteration, this will split the input
      into individual words. On subsequent iterations, this does nothing.
e10   Push "10".
x     Use this to permute the (reversed) word on top of the stack. In
      particular, the word is rearranged with the same permutation that is
      required to sort the string "10", which means the first two letters
      get swapped (which correspond to the last two letters of the actual
      word).
R     Reverse the swapped word.
o     Print it.
.n$@  If there are no words left on the stack, terminate the program.
```

Comment: Just noticed that the letter swap can be done in three bytes (`h~Z`) instead of four (`e10x`), but I'm not seeing a way to adjust the layout to actually save a byte overall with that.

Answer (score 2):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/brainfuck), <s>109</s> 100 bytes

Edit: don’t have to handle one letter words

```
,[>++++[-<-------->],]>+[-<[>++++[<++++++++>-]<[->>+<<]<]<<[->>+<<]>[[-<+>]>]<<[>+>+>]-<]>>>>>>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYrBCoNADER/JfeYfkEYKLTQQ0@9hhysbqtUrNQVP39dcemby/Bmnr@6H19L80mpMnDGRKUArxy7KItyAeJqArCq5/w7LJ8Zjt2Bc1yyPbATPKV4C/S9tNR05/twHcOb1r6LNK/1NLWBhhBjmB8b)

Prints a trailing space

#### How It Works

```
,[>++++[-<-------->],] Puts input on the tape and subtracts 32 from each character
                       This separates each word

>+[- Start the loop
   <[>++++[<++++++++>-]<[->>+<<]<] Add 32 to each letter of the word
                                   Skip this on the first iteration for the last word

   <<[->>+<<]>[[-<+>]>] Swaps the last two letters of the word
   <<[>+>+>]- If there is another word to the left continue loop
              Also set up to add a space to the end of the word
 <] End loop
 >>>>>>>[.>] Print the modified string
```

#### Previous version, 109 bytes

```
,[>++++[-<-------->],]>+[-<[>++++[<++++++++>-]<[->>+<<]<]<<[[->>+<<]>[[-<+>]>]<<[<]]>[>]<[>+>+>]-<]>>>>>>[.>]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYu9DoJAEIRfZftjfYLNJCaaWFjZXrZAWIVIkMgRHv9YyPlNMz@Z56/ux9fSfHKuIoITWbgArRR7URYJBbBKZCCIqEviP8CdBCj2UtSzO3@7lH0@iCdozulm9L201HTn@3Ad7U1r3yWa13qaWqPBUrL5sQE)

Answer (score 2):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 8 bytes

```apl
..\b
⌽⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/19PLyaJ61HP3ke9W33//w/JSMwrzuaKzC9NLVIoT81Jzk/N5QrJyCxWAKLEPIXEgoKcVC63nMyCgsz0PAWf1JKS1OIiBcei/NKUPK4Sj1SFfJcUheQMR58c17zUdIXyzIwSheJyoLaUVIUcsOogAA)

Answer (score 2):

## Google Sheets, 33 Bytes

Anonymous worksheet function that takes input from cell `A1` and outputs to the calling cell

```gs
=RegExReplace(A1,"(.)(.)\b","$2$1
```

-2 Bytes Thanks to [@KevinCruijssen](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52210/kevin-cruijssen) for the use of `(.)` over `(\w)`

Comment: Both `(\w)` can be golfed to `(.)` if I'm not mistaken. The `\b` is already an indication to look for words only. (Not entirely sure though, but it works in Java.)

Comment: @KevinCruijssen - You are absolutely correct, it can be. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 30 bytes

```julia
!s=replace(s,r"..\b"=>reverse)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HY1BCsIwEEX3OcU0qxZKwAO0UFBx0ZW4EbqJ7dBGx2nIpNaFd49V@KvHe/z7Qs7u3illUgX0ZHvMpQzamO6mqzrgC4NgkWyltVaXybI81HVeMMCK1M/43KAT2GYZrPeE6kjOezcytBgjSoAmzMvAKp4Q5v0A/dS0dGAcYXVTBFm3bECgv31WvyNlMvHkYm5L3bEuwHxq8MFxJE5f)

detect end of words with a regex `r"..\b"` and apply `reverse` on the matches

Answer (score 2):

## Curry, 33 bytes

Tested in both [KiCS2](https://www-ps.informatik.uni-kiel.de/kics2/) and [PAKCS](https://www.informatik.uni-kiel.de/%7Epakcs/).

```haskell
f(u++[x,y])=u++[y,x]
(>>=f).words
```

Curry's powerful patterns let it beat [the Haskell answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151919/56656)!

To test it you can use [Smap](https://smap.informatik.uni-kiel.de/smap.cgi?new/curry).  Just select `KiCS2 2.2.0` or `PAKCS 2.2.0` and paste the following complete code:

```
f(u++[x,y])=u++[y,x]
g=(>>=f).words
main=f "Hello world an happy day"
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>53</s> 45 bytes

```hs
u[a,b]=[b,a]
u(a:b)=a:u b
unwords.map u.words
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7Nyfn/vzQ6UScp1jY6SScxlqtUI9EqSdM20apUIYkrzbY0rzy/KKVYLzexQKFUD8z@n5uYmWdbUJSZV6KSpuQBNCJfITy/KCdF6T8A)

### Explanation

`u` is a function that swaps the last two letters of a word.  To apply it to all the words we use `words` to split the list, map it across all of the words and then use `unwords` to put it back together.

Comment: You seem to have included the `f=` from TIO in your byte count, even though it's not included in your answer here.

Comment: How do you pass the input to your program? Does `main=print$f"Hello World"` not count to the program?

Comment: @Kritzefitz Thanks! I've adjusted it.

Comment: @DanFromGermany  My program makes a point-free function `unwords.map u.words`.  You call it like any other Haskell function. `main=print$f"Hello World"` does not count because my submission is a function and not a program.

Answer (score 1):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

```
#vy`sðJ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fuawyofjwBq///0s8UhXyXVIUkjMcfXJc81LTFcozM0oUissTCwpSUhVyUktKUouDAA)

-1 thanks to [Magic Octopus Urn](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/59376/magic-octopus-urn).

Prints one trailing space.

Comment: This is 11 bytes

Comment: @DanFromGermany No, 05AB1E has a [code page](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/blob/master/docs/code-page.md) in which this can be represented as 8 bytes.

Comment: Can you run the program represented in 8 bytes?

Comment: @DanFromGermany Yes, the 05AB1E interpreter can run this program from a file in the 05AB1E encoding.

Comment: @ETHproductions um, what?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Uh, I 100% didn't mean to post that. Thought I hit cancel...

Comment: [Try it online (7-bytes)](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9fuawyofjwBq///8sz8hUyixVKMlKLUgE "05AB1E – Try It Online") if trailing spaces are allowed (can't use in-line code for that lol).

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn yes, one trailing space is allowed

Comment: I didn't know `s` worked like that on lists, weird.

Comment: @MagicOctopusUrn It's not a list though, it's after `\``.

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer ` is flatten to stack? Wow, I've only ever used `~` cause I thought they were one-and-the-same.

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 19 + 1 (`-p`) = 20 bytes

```perl
s/(\w)(\w)\b/$2$1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/79YXyOmXBOEY5L0VYxUDPXT//8PycgsVgCiRIWS1OKSf/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDf7rFgAA)

Comment: Nice solution! Came up with very similar (but using `-040`). You can use `(.)` instead of `(\w)` as the input will only ever have letters to save 2. If using `-040` you can also reaplace `\b` with `$` and, using `;` instead of `/`, drop `/g`: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7/YWkNPE4hUrFWMVAz//w/JKM5UAKJEhZLUkuJ/@QUlmfl5xf91DUwMcgoA "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <strike>119</strike> 107 bytes

Edit: thanks to totallyhuman

```php
<?php foreach(explode(" ",trim(fgets(STDIN)))as$w)echo substr($w,0,strlen($w)-2).strrev(substr($w,-2))," ";
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RYxBCsIwEEWvMpQuZiCKuFUQQQRB3OgFajttAmkyTFLr7WN27t5/fJ5YKeV4EiswRuWut8hf8XFgbKAxWd2M48Q54fN1uT2IqEvtStzbCGl5p6zYrmZnKngOlWmzp21dyh/8H6okU4OHUq7eibgpwJ1z5qRw1rgM4Qc)

Comment: Can't you make `$word` a single character variable name?

Comment: @totallyhuman Yup! I wrote the full version and then compressed it, but didn't notice that. Thanks you.

Comment: PHP open tags can be omitted in the answer saving you 6 bytes.

Comment: I wonder if `fgets(STDIN)` can be omitted or replaced by `$x` too, like not all answers do count the input to their answers

Comment: `trim()` should be unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

## [sed](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/), <s>20</s> 17+1 (-r) = 18 bytes

```
s/(.)(.)\b/\2\1/g
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K05N0U3PK/3/v1hfQ08TiGKS9GOMYgz10///D8nILFYAosQ8hcSCgpxUrn/5BSWZ@XnF/3WLAA)

Comment: The TIO link does not match your posted code.  The TIO link is a few bytes longer.

Comment: Whoops, fixed the link

Comment: You can remove `|$`. It's not doing anything. (For it to do what you expect you'd need `(.)(.)(\b|$)`, but that's not necessary because `\b` already matches the end of the string.)

Comment: Whoops, meant to get rid of that. Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
foldr(%)" "
a%(b:' ':r)=b:a:' ':r
a%s=a:s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYtBi8IwFITv/oohrKjg/oFCD4KKh3rZ9bKoh2f72gRfk5Ck9N9vjLswh5lvZjTFJ4vkvr7l3kkX1suNglrQcv2oVlhVYVM/Kvq3hcaaqphHMhY1RvJn@Cl9p9BYfLwzelzVRZONT7VVP27igJmldTyWfNEmoogsyHvhgo5ivDeDRcMpcQzYBTd1tjTpxHD7Dq3eNXKwPGA2OiHO5dox5G//pe75t@2Fhpg/W@9f)

Outputs with a trailing space.

The repeated `' ':r` looks wasteful. But `a%(b:t@(' ':r))=b:a:t` is the same length and `a%(b:t)|' ':_<-t=b:a:t` is one byte longer.

---

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 41 bytes

```hs
f(a:b:t)|t<"A"=b:a:f t|1>0=a:f(b:t)
f e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBi8IwFITv@yuG4MGFFfRa7EJBxUO9qJdF9vBsX5pgmobmlV787Wbjwhxm5psxFB/sXEp6ScW9kM@nbFWlyntBhYY8N9/rMrvlG31ocMmpJ@tRoqdwQpjkImPtsXhnaNzU1ZCPD/WlfoaJR8zsmoH7nK/GRmSRB4XgOFcHZ0OwnUfNIhxHVOMwtT4TOTKGXYvGVLXbe@4wWyOIc762DPe/P6vf9Gq0oy6mVRPCHw)

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), <s>38</s> <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```
s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)( |$)/g,"$2$1 ")
```

```javascript
s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)\b/g,"$2$1")
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bYyxCsIwFEV3v@JROiSgLbpKhYKKQyfp4hiS1yQak5CkdvHfY3WUwtnuuefOXizyoH3aWCcwD02OzSFWAb1hHElNKvoF3iWt5bood@UWCpr33NnoDFbGSTKQolfMxkdB6ep/ubkRA0xouMPnktArHWGGWWDeG1xyzkZ7r6WFDlPCGKANbhR2SU0XBHcUwFXbmZNFCZNWCeI0xwWC@QWu8zN/AA)

RegExp approach courtesy @Giuseppe (although I thought of this independently), assuming words separated by only one space

-2 for only considering 1 space and add trailing space

-4 Thanks @Shaggy

Comment: Doesn't matter if there are more spaces, I think

Comment: @l4m2 But if there are more spaces then it will become a 38 for `s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)( +|$)/g,"$2$1$3")`.

Comment: @l4m2 BTW my original answer was `s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)(\s|$)/g,"$2$1$3")`

Comment: `ab abc  abcd   abcde    abcdef     ` does `ab_`, `bc_`, `cd_`, `de_`, `___`, `ef_`, `___`

Comment: @l4m2 Oh that's indeed true ;) (although I only see one space between every word)

Comment: `F=s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)(?!\w)/g,"$2$1")` same length

Comment: 32 bytes: `s=>s.replace(/(.)(.)\b/g,"$2$1")` (Or 34 bytes without grouping: `s=>s.replace(/..\b/g,([x,y])=>y+x)`)

Answer (score 1):

## PHP, 65 bytes

requires PHP 7.1 (or later)

```php
for(;$s=$argv[++$i];$s[-1]=$s[-2],$s[-2]=$c,print"$s ")$c=$s[-1];
```

takes sentence as separate command line arguments. Run with `-nr`.

---

working on a single string, **77+1 bytes**:

```php
foreach(explode(" ",$argn)as$s){$c=$s[-1];$s[-1]=$s[-2];$s[-2]=$c;echo"$s ";}
```

Run as pipe with `-nR`.

---

...  or [try them online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94f6b1111c7af847c55fb5cd47e3583972d95d5f).

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), <s>23</s> 22 bytes

```
" "/{x@prm[!#x]1}'" "\
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/X0lBSb@6oCg3uiLWsFYdyItRcsvJLCjITM9T8EktKUktLlJwLMovTclT@v8fAA)

**Example:**

```
" "/{x@prm[!#x]1}'" "\"Hello World"
"Helol Wordl"
```

**Explanation:**

Port of [FrownyFrog](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151933/69200)'s solution to save **1 byte**.

I'll come back to this.

```
" "/{prm[x]1}'" "\ / the solution
              " "\ / split input on " "
    {       }'     / apply lambda to each
     prm[x]        / permute input x
           1       / and take the 2nd result
" "/               / join with " "
```

**Previous solution:**

- `" "/-2{(x_y),|x#y}'" "\` **23 bytes**

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 35 bytes

```java
s->s.replaceAll("(.)(.)\\b","$2$1")
```

Port of [*@TaylorScott*'s Google Sheets answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/152412/52210), after I golfed two bytes. EDIT: I see it's now a port of [*Neil*'s Retina answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151947/52210) after my two golfed bytes.

**Explanation:**

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hY5PS8NAEMXv/RSPpYcEbECvRSGg4qH2oL2I9bDdjMm2m9lld9Mgks8e15qrBN7A/PvNm6M8y5V1xMfqNCojQ8Cz1Py9ADRH8p9SEba/JfAaveYaKpuSkK9Tf0iRFKKMWmELxi3GsLoLhSdnEl4ak4msyJP2@4O4Esub5bXIx/Uf6LqDSeDEn62u0KYPJpP3D8h8sv8KkdrCdrFwaRQNZ1yoTOwayeEk8ss3/6@92Y48ejLKUju7vWt0QJJkSOcMzQKPRjuna8aGYqTgUXrbVTzLxSeCva@gmnJjHphq9LqJCH2yrQjmcu1lOjMshvEH)

```java
s->                           // Method with String as both parameter and return-type
   s.replaceAll("(.)(.)       //  Replace any two characters,
                       \\b",  //  with a word-boundary after it (space or end of String)
                "$2$1")       //  With the two characters swapped
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal) `S`, 5 bytes

```
⌈ƛ÷$Ṡ
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=%E2%8C%88%C6%9B%C3%B7%24%E1%B9%A0&inputs=You%27er%20welcoem&header=&footer=)

-2 thanks to Aaron Miller.

Comment: [5 bytes](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=S&code=%E2%8C%88%C6%9B%C3%B7%24%E1%B9%A0&inputs=You'er%20welcoem&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ly](https://github.com/LyricLy/Ly), 30 bytes

```
i00I[rpr' =[ppf' 0]p0I]pfrp[o]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y6n8/z/TwMAzuqigSF3BNrqgIE1dwSC2wMAztiCtqCA6P/b/f7eczIKCzPQ8BZ/UkpLU4iIFx6L80pQ8AA)

This one reads all the input into the stack, then copies characters one at a time to the other end of the stack (with a null separator between the original and the "fixed" codepoints).  Anytime a space it found, it reverse the position of the previous two codepoints.

When the loop hits the null separator it end, then the just prints the stack.

```
i00I[rpr' =[ppf' 0]p0I]pfrp[o]
i0                              # Read all the input, then push a null
  0I                            # Copy the bottom of the stack to the top
    [                 ]p        # Loop until the null reaches the bottom of the stack
     rpr                        # Reverse, pop, reverse (delete bottom of the stack)
                    0I          # Copy the bottom of the stack to the top
        ' =                     # Is the codepoint " "?
           [p    0]p            # If-then, runs if codepoint is " "
             pf'                # Delete " ", flip two entries, add " " back
                        f       # End of input, flip the last two codepoints
                         rp     # Reverse stack, delete null
                           [o]  # Print the stack as characters
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Lexurgy](https://www.lexurgy.com/sc), 24 bytes

This kind of challenge is one of the canonical reasons for captures in Lexurgy to exist (for things like metathesis and reduplication).

Capture 2 of any character, and swap their order when they are at the end of a "word".

```bash
a:
[]$1 []$2=>$2 $1/_ $
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
ḲṪ,¥\€Ḋ€UK
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hjk0Pd67SObQ05lHTmoc7uoBkqPf////VIxLLMlOLFHIyy1KLFTIyi4GstFQ0Qh0A)

Answer (score 0):

## [SNOBOL4 (CSNOBOL4)](http://www.snobol4.org/csnobol4/), <s>136</s> 119 bytes

```
	I =INPUT
B	I SPAN(&LCASE &UCASE) . Y ARBNO(' ') =:F(O)
	Y RPOS(2) REM . Z =REVERSE(Z)
	O =O Y ' '	:(B)
O	OUTPUT =O
END
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FY0xC4MwFITn5Fe8SZOlQ@kkZIhtBMHmhcQUdJRKEURF7e9PX6c77u7jjmUd1vmWEqtB1dbFlpdkg9NWZM1dBwNZ/IuEC3SgfWlR5JBLUEUlUHLWgXcYxFWCN08a9aC8eRkfjOipRlBIICGsEKXkyDC2dEMxN/aRUjVP2zZ9FmjG8xyPHfS@ft/LDw)

Prints with a trailing space. <s>You know you've done something wrong when a language is a backronym for *StriNg Oriented and symBOlic Language* and your code is longer than Brain-Flak :(</s> now it's slightly better.

Line `B` takes `I` and replaces `(alphabetic characters saved as Y)(some number of spaces)` with the empty string.

The following line extracts the last 2 characters of `Y` as `Z` and replaces them as `Z` reversed, then the next line concatenates `O`, `Y`, and a single space character.

Finally, it prints when `I` no longer matches the required pattern in line `B`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Clean](https://clean.cs.ru.nl), <s>75</s> 59 bytes

*-16 from Laikoni*

```
@[a,b]=[b,a]
@[a,b,' ':c]=[b,a,' ': @c]
@[a:b]=[a: @b]
@e=e
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCsMgEATQe79ib17sDwQEA6VQyK1H8bCabRDUBDWH/Hy3ib3NmxkfCTOndd4jQcKQWRuUzirjJNpbhxQgBv@vegbt@zRcPzzpTpIifjcsDRRoMOIZw7aFJcNErVEtMJZ1n7Ow/PWfiEvl@2vix5ExBV9/)

Comment: This seems to work fine without `import StdEnv`.

Comment: Also moving `@[]=[]` to the bottom and replacing it by `@e=e` saves two more bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JcrBCsMgEATQe79ib17sDwQEA6VQyK1H8bCabRDUBDWH/Hy3ib3NmxkfCTOndd4jQcKQWRuUzirjJNpbhxQgBv@vegbt@zRcPzzpTpIifjcsDRRoMOIZw7aFJcNErVEtMJZ1n7Ow/PWfiEvl@2vix5ExBV9/ "Clean – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Standard ML (MLton)](http://www.mlton.org/), <s>92</s> 77 bytes

```ml
implode o foldr(fn(a,b:: #" "::r)=>b::a:: #" "::r|(a,r)=>a::r)[#" "]o explode
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY3BCkIhFER/ZbCND@oHBIM2rfqDiPChhnD1is@iRf9u6uZtBuYcmNkinSJVTu1jCJ5Chm4hZmLrwPBMtkifpDmuSuEgIJQqiz73Znbw635QM@R9wAfDfefKHH5CI5eQqpwX4tozh1fCzdXqtoJL4bdNYml/) Based on [xnor's Haskell solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151965/56433).

---

#### Previous 92 byte version

```ml
fun f(a::b:: #" "::r)=b::a:: #" "::f r|f(x::r)=x::f r|f r=r
fun$s=implode(f(explode(s^" ")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Pcs7DgIhFIXh3lWc4BRQuIGbUNhYuQYNZsCQ8MqFmVC4dyRq7M6Xk7/GcIqh5TSG2xKcNEQPIhwFBBErPWH@duCXk/1z9B/Bmg@zXar2sYS8Wumk7d9Vb7NTSo3dBNyhUdinJheIS/Cl@GfC1bZmK@PMeVuTUOMN) Example usage: `$ "Flippign Lettesr Aroudn"` yields `"Flipping Letters Around "`.

#### Ungolfed

```ml
fun f (a :: b :: #" " :: r) = b :: a :: #" " :: f r
  | f              (x :: r) = x :: f r
  | f                    r  = r

fun g s = implode (f (explode (s ^ " ")))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fU67CgIxEOzzFUO0SAp/4MDCxspvUCKXHIG82OQkhf8eE05EG6fY2R1mmM3eHbwrMbRm1gADoTBNuI@x4@CDSeK4KepbNiAGPDv/QNRPpv6xbSB0GzE2uhfkflifXJw1RH9F1/eece2dXErZHsrh1n2JbChiD352NiW7BFx0KToTThTXOXDZXg)

Answer (score 0):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) [`-S`](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/), <s>7</s> 6 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

A port of [Jonathan's Jelly solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/151904/58974).

```
¸Ëá ÅÎ
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&flags=LVM&code=uMvhIMXO&input=IlRoaXMgaXMgYW4gYXBwbGUi)

```
¸Ëá ÅÎ     :Implicit input of string
¸          :Split on spaces
 Ë         :Map
  á        :  Permutations
    Å      :  Slice off the first element
     Î     :  Get the first element
           :Implicit output joined with spaces
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 72 bytes

```
x""<>(Characters[StringSplit@x][[;;,#]]&/@{;;-3,-1,-2})~Riffle~" "
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcvNSsNAFIbhvVfxcQRRSCjqMiop/uCiC2m7kZDFkJxkBieTYeaUFEq7dSl4B15hLyGmhXf1wtMp0dwpMZUam8dxe/z9I3p4un7WKqhKOMRiJcG4duWtkXxbFkWWJZdleTXLd1mW3ifpbZLe7W@OP9@HpWkaywcCjR@TERRoMMuxo7VWLn5RAvrsNxwwsK167k5jrU3ElHJQ3lue3gVAb9Z4b1qHBYtwDJiHflO7k5B3Rv9So9LzhX113GIwWhCHydcMewZL2qMc/wE)

Another approach using manipulation of character list and take parts instead of string regex.

The two Unicode characters are `\[Function]` and `\[Transpose]` in private use area of Mathematica, take 3 bytes each.

### 74 bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYvBSsNAFEX3fsXjCdJCQlCXVZnSKi66kLYbCVk8kpfM4GQyzLySQmk/wj/wC/2EOBXu4nIOpyfR3JOYmqb2eTr@fv8gPr3MZpTebVlSVc0LdVos8scsv8/yh/NdoVaaAtXCIaqdBOO6nbdG1HF@2Zq2tXxBwOkjCYESWigUnHCvycUvzAA/hwMHGNnWA/dXsNcmQho5IO8tJ3YDgG/WeG86BxsW4RhgGYZD466FvDMM6wZqvdzYV8cdjEYLxDH1DYP9D7Z4hmr6Aw)

Answer (score 0):

## Excel VBA, 78 Bytes

Anonymous VBE immediate window that takes input from range `A1` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
For Each s in Split([A1]):l=Len(s):?Left(s,l-2)Right(s,1)Mid(s,l-1,1)" ";:Next
```

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 53 bytes

```
$*.each{|x|print x[0,x.length-2]+x[-2,2].reverse," "}
```

The program takes input through command line arguments (formatted as a regular sentence, without quotes).

$* is a shorthand for ARGV, therefore i can iterate over each of the words, already in an array.

Only thing that bugs me is that awful x.length-2 snippet. I would prefer to use x.last(-2), but i believe that is only in RoR.

Called like:

```
ruby file.rb Helol Wordl
```

So that each word becomes a parameter. (Not wrapped in quotes)

Comment: [Doesn’t return the correct results for me](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0VLLzUxOaO6pqKmoCgzr0ShItpAp0IvJzUvvSRD1yhWuyJa10jHKFavKLUstag4VUdJQan2////JR6pCvkuKQrJGY4@Oa55qekK5ZkZJQrF5YkFBSmpCjmpJSWpxUEA). The letters aren’t swapped on all the words.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder It is because TIO passes the argument in quotes :) Add a argument for each word, and it works

Comment: [This](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/X0VLLzUxOaO6pqKmoCgzr0ShItpAp0IvJzUvvSRD1yhWuyJa10jHKFavKLUstag4VUdJQan2////JR6p//NdUv4nZzj65LjmpaYDAA) works, in practice, atleast on windows you can pass arguments without quotes, hence you can type it as if you typed a regular sentence

Answer (score 0):

## [Clojure](https://clojure.org/), <s>122</s> 117 bytes

-5 bytes by shortcutting the indices of the characters to swap

```clj
(fn[p](map #(let[l(count %)v(vec %)y(dec l)z(- l 2)](apply str(assoc v y(v z)z(v y))))(clojure.string/split p #" ")))
```

It's a shame that most of Clojure's String function are tucked away inside of `Clojure.string`, and that there are no good ways of manipulating the characters of Strings directly. `clojure.string/split` is atrociously long, and the conversion to-and-from vectors added quite a lot. I might be able to shave off a couple bytes by shortcutting the trailing indices, but this is the only decent algorithm I could think of.

```clj
(defn flip-last [phrase]
  (let [words (clojure.string/split phrase #" ")]

    ; For each word...
    (map #(let [len (count %)
                ; Need to turn the string into a vector so we can manipulate it using indices
                vec-word (vec %)]

            ; ... then turn the vector of characters back into a String.
            (apply str
               ; Associate the element at the second last index with the element at the last index,
               ;  and vice-versa...
              (assoc vec-word (dec len) (vec-word (- len 2))
                              (- len 2) (vec-word (dec len)))))

         words)))
```

Answer (score 0):

## [QuadR](https://github.com/abrudz/QuadRS), 8 bytes

```apl
..\b
⌽⍵M
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyxNTCn6/19PLyaJ61HP3ke9W33//w/JSMwrzuaKzC9NLVIoT81Jzk/N5QrJyCxWAKLEPIXEgoKcVC63nMyCgsz0PAWf1JKS1OIiBcei/NKUPK4Sj1SFfJcUheQMR58c17zUdIXyzIwSheJyoLaUVIUcsOogAA)

`..\b` any two characters followed by a word boundary

gets replaced with

`⌽⍵M` the reverse of the **M**atch

---

Equivalent to the following 18-byte Dyalog APL function:

```apl
'..\b'⎕R{⌽⍵.Match}
```

Answer (score 0):

### PHP4 (48 chars)

Given *$argv[1]* as a [command line](https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php) argument :

```php
echo preg_replace('#(.)(.)\b#','$2$1',$argv[1]);
```

### PHP7.4 (48 chars)

The function **$f** is inverting the last two chars of every word :

```php
$f=fn($s)=>preg_replace('#(.)(.)\b#','$2$1',$s);
```

[Try it Online](https://tio.run/##hZFBSwMxEIXPza8Y00CzUAS91q0UqvTQU@nFk4TN7CZ0mw2T1Crib1@TXQsepIaBDMP33mMSb3z/8OiNZyJiiAFKUETqQzK@N8qFA4f/TrmEgT0EPmf8pTshwRnbqsMjv65KLOHIHjGL98YGSKUcKO9b5Fcjg4VUTmUW26x/bq33tnGwxZjWIVhRd9KO/6UfWdeMLIWBdTrbxA1Ct9ZQmdW2fXLYwNmaCOGcgjRCO5jv@GATcQOdXl/YJu1joxlZ1CO7yy9TLHpRl7WTIhTl0hM2r4S@VRXK2VTeFqlgOptzcS/ugKc7AC8WjNUdoaqM/PkfFUA09g1dThf47rGKqAv2ySaCMP@fqOVIJPVlFskeZe7zzNYw9HBT/naYTLRFyZGoo5w8YV@MDSOvQkCdZn3/DQ) - Usage :

```php
echo $f('Flippign Lettesr Aroudn');
```

Both versions are using 's [PCRE](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.pcre.php) Text Processing Functions.

**Info**: Support for [PHP4](https://www.php.net/manual/php4.php) has been discontinued since 2008 but same code still works in PHP8.1.

### [Mathematica](https://www.wolfram.com/language/) (58 chars)

```
f=StringReplace[#,RegularExpression["(.)(.)\\b"]:>"$2$1"]&
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##fVHBSsQwED3brxjiIspWqYIXocLCrqywB6l7kW4OsZ2mYdNJSVLq39e0ZQWRdZhL3pt582bSCF9jI7wqxDBU6bu3imSGrRYF5pdxhrLTwm6@WovOKUM5u767CXk4fDL@9MwWD4t7xq8GghSSKHqtcqhytq8FuSPjF2OkKUzA0bHpHcNySTHQbQqPSQL81PRhOrTQoy4MNnPv2BpgizPcIIOzcVZ3XysHIQWBaFsdNPiPK6cgJImRQf1b/bzTF63aVkmCHXqPzsLKmq6kSXjUnXmSM2/dxFPJ/lnebxHMuoSiXu30hlBCr2oPrg/GSgQ9DcrCVUZ9j1sw5fpULMN5lK/nYizn4ixc@8@w6C18r4ccCPjwDQ)

Answer (score 0):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 50 bytes

```factor
[ " "split [ 2 cut* reverse append ] map " "join ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RU67TsMwFN3zFUceGTogscBUiVelioHHgKoOlnNITN1rc31DKD8fki5IZzrvDx8s6/T2snl6uEYtKZpF6VD5NVAC64o/pr7@EzhQhQlFaXYqGsXQUag@xV9vMUvFTdO4195LPbjGveeBipEpZB7dIsSKGV7gS0mcqfsUS4mdYDt3sirWmodWZsUeiXzbIvTrbboTdhhjb6jjHG2JdPY/u2bawcGd/2OHS4TBLqD8plYuM5QWexx9WWyfOQr20xVkOXDCqiIkep3@AA)

Factor's regular expressions don't support backreferences for [philosophical reasons](https://docs.factorcode.org/content/article-regexp-theory.html), so here's (possibly) the next best thing. It splits the input on spaces, applies a quotation to each word, and joins them with a space into a single string. Here's how the mapping quotation works:

```
          ! "Flipping"
2 cut*    ! "Flippi" "ng"
reverse   ! "Flippi" "gn"
append    ! "Flippign"
```